# Whether there generate QR code in my project directory will get mix when multi people using it?

Tags: php, html

I have a question about the application generate QR code image.

I have an application when clients click a button there will generate a QR code image, my way is store in the project library, then print `<img>` with the `url` to the screen. then clients can see it.

[image]

But I have a doubt, if there are multi clients using the QR code at the same time, whether there will get a mix?

my code is bellow:

```
function generate_qrcode($url){

    $filename = 'hante_qrcode.png';
    $errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
    $matrixPointSize = 4;
    //generate QR code image
    $o = QRcode::png($url, $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($o);

    print_r('<img src="hante_qrcode.png">');

}
```

---

if there get mix, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question: there will get a mix? Answer: yes, they will get mixed for sure.

Comment: You follow the wrong approach. Stop thinking in "files" when implementing web logic. You should not create a physical file in the server side file system at all, actually the server should, for security reasons, never even be able to write files in the location of your scripts or library. Instead your `<img ...>` tag refers to a script which generates the qrcode "on the fly" and simply sends it to the requesting client. That way you also prevent collisions between multiple requesting clients.

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: @arkascha How to understand your ` Instead your <img ...> tag refers to a script which generates the qrcode "on the fly" and simply sends it to the requesting client. `? can you give a demonstration?

Comment: `<img src="create_qrcode.php?url=$url">`. That sends a request to a script you implement. That script creates the QRCode, but does NOT save it into a file but "streams" it out immediately. You can add http headers to signal what mimetype the response is to the client, here a png image. You will find endless examples for this here on SO and out on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I have a doubt, if there are multi clients using the QR code at the same time, whether there will get a mix?

`yes`

**how to solve this problem?**

there are two ways to solve this problem

1. you can provide unique name for every files like using timestamp using `time()` function or with `user ID`. cause as per you are passing parameters while generating qr code you need to store the file. without saving file also possible but in that case you can't configure pixel size and frame size. you can refer this for [PHP QR code-Examples](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=003)
2. don't store image on server and find some js to generate qr code directly from client side.

   - having a one demo for that check if you can use it

```js
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");
qrcode.makeCode('https://stackoverflow.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will be overwritten.

**Solution 1**

Create unique filename for every image. This way you can save your images for use later. Another benefit of this, you don't have to create image again for same url.

```
$filename = md5($url) . ".png";
if(!file_exists($filename)){
    $o = QRcode::png($url, $filename, ...);
}
echo '<img src="'.$filename.'">';
```

**Solution 2**

If you don't want to save images for disk space reasons you can serve image directly. In your code, user sends request to index.php and fetch image address as response. After then browser makes another request to get image. You can return image rather than returning html.

```
// image.php
// Still we want to give uniqe filename because we can get another request while one request is processing
$filename = md5(microtime) . "_qr.png"; 
$o = QRcode::png($url, $filename, ...);

$image = file_get_contents($filename);
// remove the file after stored in a variable
unlink($filename);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($image));
echo $image;

// index.html
<img src="image.php?url=someurl">
```